# Text highlighting (label effect) using CSS

Tags: css, typography

I want to create a text style similar to a label. Looky here:

[image]

I can nearly do it using just: http://jsfiddle.net/STApE/

```
p{display: inline; background: yellow;}
```

BUT, I want to add some padding. When I do, things go downhill. Same happens if I add a border: http://jsfiddle.net/JN72d/

Any ideas on a simple way to achieve this effect?

Comment: You'll need to tinker with `line-height:XXpx` - working on a sample.

Comment: It's unclear what actual effect you want to accomplish. Please give a bit more info on how you want it to look, and not what you think would be the right way to sort it. (Ie. padding)

Comment: @anothershrubery:  A picture is worth a thousand words?

Comment: As Dutchie says line-height + padding will give the effect of spacing the text out and keeping the yellow background. If that is what you want then have a fiddle and see what works best for you. I would post this as an answer but Dutchie should take credit.

Comment: @Stephen: It is not clear from the picture what he was trying to do with the padding as the picture doesn't include the padding, which is why I asked for clarification.

Comment: @anothershrubery the picture has small padding around the outside, especially visible in comparison to the jfiddle link I posted, where the text is exactly inline with the yellow background. You are right though, I should have made the padding slightly bigger in the image.

Comment: I see padding in the picture.

Comment: It certainly is 5px, maybe 1 or 2, which is probably what got me confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to achieve it by modifying your DOM structure a bit:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zp2Cm/2/

Comment: This works well. Feels a bit messy, but something in this style would only usually be for a small amount of text, so I guess it isn't such a big deal.

Comment: Actually I had horrible <br />'s in there anyway so this isn't much difference. Thanks.

Comment: What is the point of SPAN wraps if in 95% of possible cases the text should be dynamical and it's length can be changed any time?..
This solution is useful only for static ones.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap each line with a span. Set the span to be block-level. Apply background and padding to span.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<p>` you could use `<span>` and `float`:

```
<style type="text/css">
span {
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    clear: left;
}
</style>

<span>highlighting the text</span>
<span>like this</span>
<span>using just css</span>
<span>is harder</span>
<span>than it looks</span>
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cgQwR/1/).

Answer (score 1):

this sort of thing you are looking for?

Was a little long winded! hense the 44 in the url . If you can live without p tags then should be ok for you

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/STApE/44/)

Comment: Not as semantic as using `p` and `span` tags, but it works.  +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want by changing `display:inline` to `display:inline-block`. This has some browse compatibility issues (depending on your target set):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: This does not work.  This makes the entire `p` tag turn into a yellow block.

Answer (score 0):

Could use `<pre>`? Leaves it formatted how you want it

Comment: I have never actually used <pre>, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I think `<pre>` could be a great use case for this...  hmm...  maybe.  For some reason I cannot give you a +1 unless you change your answer.  Could you update with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Add spans to your paragraph like this:

```
<p class="p1">
    <span>Highlighting the text</span><br/>
    <span>like this</span><br />
    <span>using just CSS</span><br />
    <span>is as easy</span><br />
    <span>as it looks.</span>
</p>
```

And add the following CSS:

```
p.p1{display: inline; background: yellow;}
span {padding: 5px; background: yellow; display: inline-block;}
```

Notice the **display: inline-block** attribute. I forked your code: http://jsfiddle.net/eliekhoury/JN72d/27/

Comment: I would lose the `br` tags and float left with display block.  Less markup.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hard task to do...

BUT :) I found a Great Article for this!

With the following solutions you can make your `Dinamic text` highlighted without using wrap for each line.

**Article with Demos**: http://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

**Enjoy!)**