# Change background color of all text with a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just started learning the basics of chrome extensions. Using a "Page Redder" extension, which changes the background color of the entire webpage, as a template I would like to make an extension that changes the background color of all text.

Page Redder from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples: 
background.js:

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
  });
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page red"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Can I change the following lines of code to select all text instead?

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
```

I tried changing it to:

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS("content.css")
```

with content.css:

```
input[type='text']
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

but with no success.

Comment: I don't know anything about Chrome extensions, but `input[type='text']` refers to `<input>` fields, *not* all text on the page.  To do that, you'd need to select `<p>` tags or whatever `<div>`s may contain the text.  There's not a CSS selector for all text of any sort that I am aware of.

Comment: There will be a problem with specificity..

Comment: Unfortunately, highlighting only text using CSS is nontrivial; see for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/18746649/689161 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/4899373/689161

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! I'm trying to eventually create a custom highlighter tool and I figured it would be best to take it one step at a time. Looks like I will look into word searching first.